# How can I calculate the nth percentile from an array of doubles in PHP?

Tags: php, math, statistics

I have a large array of doubles and I need to calculate the 75th and 90th percentile values for the array. What's the most efficient way to do this via a function?

Comment: sort the array, count the number of values, calculate the 75% and 90% entries et voila

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been awhile since statistics, so I could be off here - but here's a crack at it.

```
function get_percentile($percentile, $array) {
    sort($array);
    $index = ($percentile/100) * count($array);
    if (floor($index) == $index) {
         $result = ($array[$index-1] + $array[$index])/2;
    }
    else {
        $result = $array[floor($index)];
    }
    return $result;
}

$scores = array(22.3, 32.4, 12.1, 54.6, 76.8, 87.3, 54.6, 45.5, 87.9);

echo get_percentile(75, $scores);
echo get_percentile(90, $scores);
```

Comment: To fix index out of range:  $index = ($percentile/100) * (count($array) - 1);

Answer (score 19):

The answer above could throw an *undefined index notice* if you use the higher percent value (100) and does not return correct values according to Excel PERCENTILE function. You can [see here an example of how it fails](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9b70541a4c54a7ad5d087ed14c66752055eadfa).

I've written a function in PHP according the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) Second varitant, which is the one used in Excel. This function is also protected from a non percentual value (out of range).

```
function getPercentile($array, $percentile)
{
    $percentile = min(100, max(0, $percentile));
    $array = array_values($array);
    sort($array);
    $index = ($percentile / 100) * (count($array) - 1);
    $fractionPart = $index - floor($index);
    $intPart = floor($index);

    $percentile = $array[$intPart];
    $percentile += ($fractionPart > 0) ? $fractionPart * ($array[$intPart + 1] - $array[$intPart]) : 0;

    return $percentile;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Working off of Mark's function above, I believe the function should actually be:

```php
function get_percentile($percentile, $array) {
    sort($array);
    $index = (($percentile/100) * (count($array))-1;
    if (floor($index) == $index) {
         return $array[$index];
    }
    else {
        return ($array[floor($index)] + $array[ceiling($index)])/2;
    }
}
```

I think there are three things that needed to be corrected:

1. Needed to reduce `count` by one in order to avoid an out-of-range index (mentioned above)
2. If the calculated `index` is an integer, then you should be able to just return the index. You only need to average values when the `index` is not an integer.
3. For the average, instead of arbitrarily subtracting one from index, it's better to use `floor` and `ceiling` to get the indices to average